# MySQL not Sorting Data Correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have been using MySQL for a long time and I have never run across this issue. I have a table that stores the scores for an application. For some reason, when I sort by `score ASC`, the highest score is shown first with the lowest score being last. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Here is my query:

```
SELECT category, subject, max(score) as score FROM scores 
WHERE customer_id = 1086 AND category = 'Business' 
GROUP BY subject ORDER BY score ASC
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: This may be happening as the `Score` is being treated as a string instead of a number.

Comment: Is there a way to change this?

Comment: can you dump your table structure here?some time incorrect data type gone crazy while sorting.

Comment: Try to `cast` your score before sorting in SQL and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the datatype of score from string (eg varchar/text) to a number (eg int). That should solve the sorting issue.

When the values are sorted on string basis (alphabetically), the '6' in '60' comes before '8'.

As a temporary work-around you can also try `order by score+0 asc` to try and convert your value into a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting `CAST(max(score) AS INTEGER) as Score` and then `ORDER BY Score`.